# concatenate two columns with equal space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**edit**

```
SELECT  (dbo.County.CountyName + ' (' + dbo.State.StateName + ' ) ') 
AS CountyName from Table1
```

i am adding two columns for an example:

```
CountyName + '(' + StateName + ')'
```

how can i make sure or have fixed width of CountyName so that it looks neat/clean

for an example:

```
Torrance     (California)
Torrance     (Chicago)
Cook         (Chicago)
....
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you use your concatenation so we know more about the usage and setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CountyName + space(20-len(CountyName)) + '(' + StateName + ')'...
```

Comment: but the StateName is not align

Comment: @Abu: Where are you viewing the data? It may look wrong in SSMS depending on your font, but if you cut/paste the results to something like Notepad, it should look right.

Comment: yes i am looking in SSMS and if i copy copy and paste in the notepad it looks perfect... hmmm but the font issue i remember that once i had this problem....

Comment: @Joe Is Courier (or fixed-width font) your default for Notepad? I don't think it is in a default Windows installation

Comment: @cyberwiki: Lucida Console (fixed width).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, SSMS eats up duplicate spaces (at least sometimes), when displaying data in a grid. If you change to 'display as text', it should display all the strings correctly, using a fixed-width font too.